# subscript out of bounds while extracting Tags

Tags: r

I have an annotation file which i want to read and store the Tags to append it in the final file in order to achieve that

my code

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
#print(getwd())

library('argparse')
library('dplyr')
# suppressMessages(library('argparse'))

get_args <- function(){
  parser <- ArgumentParser(description='Run methylKit for treated-vs-untreated groups')
  parser$add_argument("-sf",  "--sampleSheet", help='SampleSheet file, defined: name/file/group',    type="character", required=TRUE)
  parser$add_argument("-t",  "--tags", help='tags seperated by |, eg: Tags:Colon|Primary tissue - fresh or fresh frozen', type="character", required=FALSE)          
        args <- parser$parse_args(gsub("'|\"| ", "_", commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)))
  return (args)
}
args <- get_args()
print("*************")
print(args$genome)
# load library
cat(date(),'- loading libraries\n')
#library('methylKit')
# suppressMessages(library('methylKit'))
# suppressMessages(library('genomation'))
library('stringr')
# suppressMessages(library('stringr'))


# load sample data 
cat(date(),'- loading sample data\n')
samplesheet = readLines(args$sampleSheet)
# samplesheet=gsub(" ", "", samplesheet, fixed = TRUE)
print(samplesheet)

#fetch comparison number from name
tmpSamplesheetName = args$sampleSheet
comparisonNumber = stringr::str_replace(stringr::str_split(stringr::str_split(tmpSamplesheetName,".samplesheet")[[1]][1], "_")[[1]][4],"C","")


all_lines <- readLines(tmpSamplesheetName)

# Find the line index where "Tags" is present

# Find the line index where "Tags" is present
tags_line_index <- grep("Tags", all_lines)

# Print the contents of all_lines
print(all_lines)

# Print the length of all_lines and tags_line_index
print(length(all_lines))
print(tags_line_index)

# Check if tags_line_index is within bounds
if (tags_line_index <= length(all_lines)) {
  # Extract the Tags information from the last column
  tags_column_index <- length(strsplit(all_lines[tags_line_index], "\t")[[1]])
  tags <- sapply(all_lines[(tags_line_index + 1):length(all_lines)], function(line) {
    line_parts <- strsplit(line, "\t")[[1]]
    
    # Debugging step 1: Print the line_parts and tags_column_index for each line
    print(line_parts)
    print(tags_column_index)
    
    if (length(line_parts) >= tags_column_index && tags_column_index > 0) {
      return(line_parts[tags_column_index])
    } else {
      return(NA)
    }
  }, USE.NAMES = FALSE, simplify = TRUE)
  
  # Debugging step 2: Print the extracted tags
  print(tags)
  
  # Remove NA values
  tags <- na.omit(tags)
  
  # Debugging step 3: Print the non-NA tags
  print(tags)
  
  # Combine the extracted Tags into a single string
  formatted_tags <- paste(":", paste(tags, collapse = "|"), sep = "")
} else {
  # Handle the case where "Tags" is not present
  stop("Error: 'Tags' not found in the sample sheet.")
}
```

To rest it i ran the above as such

```
Rscript.exe m1_test.R -sf test_v1.txt
```

The file which im testing is this

```
GEO_ID  Title   Platform    Description Group   Sample_Name Replicate
GSM5116869  lPC-STD1    GPL17021    lPC-STD_dentate gyrus; Methylated cytosines converted to uracil by treatment with sodium bisulfite  Late_progenitor_cells_(LPC)_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_standard_conditions    lPCSTD  1
GSM5116870  lPC-STD2    GPL17021    lPC-STD_dentate gyrus; Methylated cytosines converted to uracil by treatment with sodium bisulfite  Late_progenitor_cells_(LPC)_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_standard_conditions    lPCSTD  2
GSM5116871  lPC-STD3    GPL17021    lPC-STD_dentate gyrus; Methylated cytosines converted to uracil by treatment with sodium bisulfite  Late_progenitor_cells_(LPC)_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_standard_conditions    lPCSTD  3
GSM5116875  lPC-ENR1    GPL17021    lPC-ENR_dentate gyrus; Methylated cytosines converted to uracil by treatment with sodium bisulfite  Late_progenitor_cells_(LPC)_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_enriched_conditions    lPCENR  1
GSM5116876  lPC-ENR2    GPL17021    lPC-ENR_dentate gyrus; Methylated cytosines converted to uracil by treatment with sodium bisulfite  Late_progenitor_cells_(LPC)_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_enriched_conditions    lPCENR  2
GSM5116877  lPC-ENR3    GPL17021    lPC-ENR_dentate gyrus; Methylated cytosines converted to uracil by treatment with sodium bisulfite  Late_progenitor_cells_(LPC)_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_enriched_conditions    lPCENR  3
GSM5116859  NSPC-STD1   GPL19057    NSPC-STD_dentate gyrus; Methylated cytosines converted to uracil by treatment with sodium bisulfite Early_progenitor_cells_(NSPCs)_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_standard_conditions NSPCSTD 1
GSM5116860  NSPC-STD2   GPL19057    NSPC-STD_dentate gyrus; Methylated cytosines converted to uracil by treatment with sodium bisulfite Early_progenitor_cells_(NSPCs)_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_standard_conditions NSPCSTD 2
GSM5116861  NSPC-STD3   GPL19057    NSPC-STD_dentate gyrus; Methylated cytosines converted to uracil by treatment with sodium bisulfite Early_progenitor_cells_(NSPCs)_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_standard_conditions NSPCSTD 3
GSM5116862  NSPC-STD4   GPL19057    NSPC-STD_dentate gyrus; Methylated cytosines converted to uracil by treatment with sodium bisulfite Early_progenitor_cells_(NSPCs)_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_standard_conditions NSPCSTD 4
GSM5116863  NSPC-STD5   GPL19057    NSPC-STD_dentate gyrus; Methylated cytosines converted to uracil by treatment with sodium bisulfite Early_progenitor_cells_(NSPCs)_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_standard_conditions NSPCSTD 5
GSM5116864  NSPC-ENR1   GPL19057    NSPC-ENR_dentate gyrus; Methylated cytosines converted to uracil by treatment with sodium bisulfite Early_progenitor_cells_(NSPCs)_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_enriched_conditions NSPCENR 1
GSM5116865  NSPC-ENR2   GPL19057    NSPC-ENR_dentate gyrus; Methylated cytosines converted to uracil by treatment with sodium bisulfite Early_progenitor_cells_(NSPCs)_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_enriched_conditions NSPCENR 2
GSM5116866  NSPC-ENR3   GPL19057    NSPC-ENR_dentate gyrus; Methylated cytosines converted to uracil by treatment with sodium bisulfite Early_progenitor_cells_(NSPCs)_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_enriched_conditions NSPCENR 3
GSM5116867  NSPC-ENR4   GPL19057    NSPC-ENR_dentate gyrus; Methylated cytosines converted to uracil by treatment with sodium bisulfite Early_progenitor_cells_(NSPCs)_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_enriched_conditions NSPCENR 4
GSM5116868  NSPC-ENR5   GPL19057    NSPC-ENR_dentate gyrus; Methylated cytosines converted to uracil by treatment with sodium bisulfite Early_progenitor_cells_(NSPCs)_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_enriched_conditions NSPCENR 5
GSM5116872  lPC-STD4    GPL19057    lPC-STD_dentate gyrus; Methylated cytosines converted to uracil by treatment with sodium bisulfite  Late_progenitor_cells_(LPC)_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_standard_conditions    lPCSTD  4
GSM5116873  lPC-STD5    GPL19057    lPC-STD_dentate gyrus; Methylated cytosines converted to uracil by treatment with sodium bisulfite  Late_progenitor_cells_(LPC)_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_standard_conditions    lPCSTD  5
GSM5116874  lPC-STD6    GPL19057    lPC-STD_dentate gyrus; Methylated cytosines converted to uracil by treatment with sodium bisulfite  Late_progenitor_cells_(LPC)_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_standard_conditions    lPCSTD  6
GSM5116878  lPC-ENR4    GPL19057    lPC-ENR_dentate gyrus; Methylated cytosines converted to uracil by treatment with sodium bisulfite  Late_progenitor_cells_(LPC)_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_enriched_conditions    lPCENR  4
GSM5116879  lPC-ENR5    GPL19057    lPC-ENR_dentate gyrus; Methylated cytosines converted to uracil by treatment with sodium bisulfite  Late_progenitor_cells_(LPC)_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_enriched_conditions    lPCENR  5
GSM5116880  lPC-ENR6    GPL19057    lPC-ENR_dentate gyrus; Methylated cytosines converted to uracil by treatment with sodium bisulfite  Late_progenitor_cells_(LPC)_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_enriched_conditions    lPCENR  6
GSM5116881  Neuron-STD1 GPL19057    Neuron-STD_dentate gyrus; Methylated cytosines converted to uracil by treatment with sodium bisulfite   Neurons_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_standard_conditions    NeuronSTD   1
GSM5116882  Neuron-STD2 GPL19057    Neuron-STD_dentate gyrus; Methylated cytosines converted to uracil by treatment with sodium bisulfite   Neurons_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_standard_conditions    NeuronSTD   2
GSM5116883  Neuron-STD3 GPL19057    Neuron-STD_dentate gyrus; Methylated cytosines converted to uracil by treatment with sodium bisulfite   Neurons_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_standard_conditions    NeuronSTD   3
GSM5116884  Neuron-STD4 GPL19057    Neuron-STD_dentate gyrus; Methylated cytosines converted to uracil by treatment with sodium bisulfite   Neurons_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_standard_conditions    NeuronSTD   4
GSM5116885  Neuron-ENR1 GPL19057    Neuron-ENR_dentate gyrus; Methylated cytosines converted to uracil by treatment with sodium bisulfite   Neurons_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_enriched_conditions    NeuronENR   1
GSM5116886  Neuron-ENR2 GPL19057    Neuron-ENR_dentate gyrus; Methylated cytosines converted to uracil by treatment with sodium bisulfite   Neurons_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_enriched_conditions    NeuronENR   2
GSM5116887  Neuron-ENR3 GPL19057    Neuron-ENR_dentate gyrus; Methylated cytosines converted to uracil by treatment with sodium bisulfite   Neurons_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_enriched_conditions    NeuronENR   3
GSM5116888  Neuron-ENR4 GPL19057    Neuron-ENR_dentate gyrus; Methylated cytosines converted to uracil by treatment with sodium bisulfite   Neurons_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_enriched_conditions    NeuronENR   4
GSM5116889  Neuron-ENR5 GPL19057    Neuron-ENR_dentate gyrus; Methylated cytosines converted to uracil by treatment with sodium bisulfite   Neurons_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_enriched_conditions    NeuronENR   5
-----   -----   -----   -----   -----       
  Comparison    Trat    Ctrl    Title   Paired  Tags    
1   Late_progenitor_cells_(LPC)_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_enriched_conditions    Late_progenitor_cells_(LPC)_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_standard_conditions    Late progenitor cells from dentate gyrus of mice housed in enriched conditions _vs_ standard    methyl  Dentate Gyrus|Stem cells|Normal vs. normal|Environmental conditions 
2   Early_progenitor_cells_(NSPCs)_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_enriched_conditions Early_progenitor_cells_(NSPCs)_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_standard_conditions Early progenitor cells from dentate gyrus of mice housed in enriched conditions _vs_ standard   methyl  Dentate Gyrus|Stem cells|Normal vs. normal|Environmental conditions 
3   Neurons_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_enriched_conditions    Neurons_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_standard_conditions    Neurons from dentate gyrus of mice housed in enriched conditions _vs_ standard  methyl  Dentate Gyrus|Neurons|Normal vs. normal|Environmental conditions    
4   Late_progenitor_cells_(LPC)_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_enriched_conditions    Early_progenitor_cells_(NSPCs)_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_enriched_conditions Dentate gyrus cells from mice housed in enriched conditions - late progenitors _vs_ early progenitors   methyl  Dentate Gyrus|Stem cells|Normal vs. normal|Environmental conditions 
5   Neurons_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_enriched_conditions    Early_progenitor_cells_(NSPCs)_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_enriched_conditions Dentate gyrus cells from mice housed in enriched conditions - neurons_vs_ early progenitors methyl  Dentate Gyrus|Neurons|Stem cells|Normal vs. normal|Environmental conditions 
6   Late_progenitor_cells_(LPC)_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_standard_conditions    Early_progenitor_cells_(NSPCs)_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_standard_conditions Dentate gyrus cells from mice housed in standard conditions - late progenitors _vs_ early progenitors   methyl  Dentate Gyrus|Stem cells|Normal vs. normal|Environmental conditions 
7   Neurons_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_standard_conditions    Early_progenitor_cells_(NSPCs)_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_standard_conditions Dentate gyrus cells from mice housed in standard conditions - neurons_vs_ early progenitors methyl  Dentate Gyrus|Neurons|Stem cells|Normal vs. normal|Environmental conditions
```

So here my objective is to extract anything that is under the **Tags** and store them similar to **comparisonNumber**.

Any suggestion or help would be really appreciated

Comment: Hello @PesKchan, often times it is very helpful to reduce your code to the part where the issue arises. In your case you can strip all the arg parsing and printing and focus on the tag extraction. Besides helping you to solve the problem by yourself, this is part of the SO etiquette for good questions. SO is a problem solving site, not a code debugging service, so you need to focus your question and code on the relevant parts.

Comment: Anyway, subscript out of bounds is an error you encounter when you subset a vector past its actual size. E.g., with `a <- c(1, 2, 3)` I can't do `a[4]`, it would be out of bounds. So the error can come from the subsetting in various places (definition of the variables group, sample, title. samples....).

Comment: okay thanks for the input ..i did run line by line it seems fine but when i put it in the full script it fails...

Comment: When you run from Rscript you may need to find the log file to find the error messages. Also add --verbose to CMD line args. At the moment we have no idea whether to default working directory matches your assumptions about locations. It also might be helpful if you used `cat` to display value of `args$sampleSheet` and other values that might be helpful is finding "surprises".

Comment: Running with `~$ Rscript m1_test.R -sf test_v1.txt` on a Terminal session on a Linux box  with the two files at the `~/` directory had no errors and what appeared to be sensible output.

Comment: @IRTFM I have created another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77548994/matching-index-from-annotation-table-while-parsing

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer. Rather it's the output that won't fit in a comment and appears to be what was printed out in response to the unlabeled `print` commands in the script. I omitted thee results of the

```
print(all_lines)
```

```
[1] 42
[1] 34
[1] "    1"                                                                                               
[2] "Late_progenitor_cells_(LPC)_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_enriched_conditions"
[3] "Late_progenitor_cells_(LPC)_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_standard_conditions"
[4] "Late progenitor cells from dentate gyrus of mice housed in enriched conditions _vs_ standard"        
[5] "methyl"                                                                                              
[6] "Dentate Gyrus|Stem cells|Normal vs. normal|Environmental conditions"                                 
[1] 6
[1] "    2"                                                                                                  
[2] "Early_progenitor_cells_(NSPCs)_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_enriched_conditions"
[3] "Early_progenitor_cells_(NSPCs)_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_standard_conditions"
[4] "Early progenitor cells from dentate gyrus of mice housed in enriched conditions _vs_ standard"          
[5] "methyl"                                                                                                 
[6] "Dentate Gyrus|Stem cells|Normal vs. normal|Environmental conditions"                                    
[1] 6
[1] "    3"                                                                           
[2] "Neurons_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_enriched_conditions"
[3] "Neurons_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_standard_conditions"
[4] "Neurons from dentate gyrus of mice housed in enriched conditions _vs_ standard"  
[5] "methyl"                                                                          
[6] "Dentate Gyrus|Neurons|Normal vs. normal|Environmental conditions"                
[1] 6
[1] "    4"                                                                                                  
[2] "Late_progenitor_cells_(LPC)_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_enriched_conditions"   
[3] "Early_progenitor_cells_(NSPCs)_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_enriched_conditions"
[4] "Dentate gyrus cells from mice housed in enriched conditions - late progenitors _vs_ early progenitors"  
[5] "methyl"                                                                                                 
[6] "Dentate Gyrus|Stem cells|Normal vs. normal|Environmental conditions"                                    
[1] 6
[1] "    5"                                                                                                  
[2] "Neurons_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_enriched_conditions"                       
[3] "Early_progenitor_cells_(NSPCs)_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_enriched_conditions"
[4] "Dentate gyrus cells from mice housed in enriched conditions - neurons_vs_ early progenitors"            
[5] "methyl"                                                                                                 
[6] "Dentate Gyrus|Neurons|Stem cells|Normal vs. normal|Environmental conditions"                            
[1] 6
[1] "    6"                                                                                                  
[2] "Late_progenitor_cells_(LPC)_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_standard_conditions"   
[3] "Early_progenitor_cells_(NSPCs)_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_standard_conditions"
[4] "Dentate gyrus cells from mice housed in standard conditions - late progenitors _vs_ early progenitors"  
[5] "methyl"                                                                                                 
[6] "Dentate Gyrus|Stem cells|Normal vs. normal|Environmental conditions"                                    
[1] 6
[1] "    7"                                                                                                  
[2] "Neurons_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_standard_conditions"                       
[3] "Early_progenitor_cells_(NSPCs)_from_dentate_gyrus_of_11wk_old_female_mice_housed_in_standard_conditions"
[4] "Dentate gyrus cells from mice housed in standard conditions - neurons_vs_ early progenitors"            
[5] "methyl"                                                                                                 
[6] "Dentate Gyrus|Neurons|Stem cells|Normal vs. normal|Environmental conditions"                            
[1] 6
character(0)
[1] 6
[1] "Dentate Gyrus|Stem cells|Normal vs. normal|Environmental conditions"        
[2] "Dentate Gyrus|Stem cells|Normal vs. normal|Environmental conditions"        
[3] "Dentate Gyrus|Neurons|Normal vs. normal|Environmental conditions"           
[4] "Dentate Gyrus|Stem cells|Normal vs. normal|Environmental conditions"        
[5] "Dentate Gyrus|Neurons|Stem cells|Normal vs. normal|Environmental conditions"
[6] "Dentate Gyrus|Stem cells|Normal vs. normal|Environmental conditions"        
[7] "Dentate Gyrus|Neurons|Stem cells|Normal vs. normal|Environmental conditions"
[8] NA                                                                           
[1] "Dentate Gyrus|Stem cells|Normal vs. normal|Environmental conditions"        
[2] "Dentate Gyrus|Stem cells|Normal vs. normal|Environmental conditions"        
[3] "Dentate Gyrus|Neurons|Normal vs. normal|Environmental conditions"           
[4] "Dentate Gyrus|Stem cells|Normal vs. normal|Environmental conditions"        
[5] "Dentate Gyrus|Neurons|Stem cells|Normal vs. normal|Environmental conditions"
[6] "Dentate Gyrus|Stem cells|Normal vs. normal|Environmental conditions"        
[7] "Dentate Gyrus|Neurons|Stem cells|Normal vs. normal|Environmental conditions"
attr(,"na.action")
[1] 8
attr(,"class")
[1] "omit"
```

I haven't gone through this for validity since you really didn't include enough comments tofigure out whbat was the intenet or what a correct answer would be.

Comment: I would like to create another question for this since i have got some clarity now what im expecting the final output